# Acegisf tag Library for jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

I have a JSF 2.0 application. Can we use `acegi-jsf` of version `1.1.3`. Can we use this tag library for JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acegi does not exist anymore. It was taken over by Spring in April 2008 and continued under the brand "Spring Security". That Acegi tag library is likely JSP targeted and not Facelets targeted. JSF 2.0 was namely introduced in December 2009, which is a long time after the Acegi takeover by Spring.

You should be looking for Spring Security JSF 2.0 tag library instead. However, a "JSF 2.0 tag library" can better be rephrased to "Facelets tag library" in order to end up with a more correct term and thus get better Google hits. You ultimately want to use this on Facelets (XHTML) files, right?

I don't do Spring, but Googling on ["Spring Security Facelets tag library"](http://google.com/search?q=spring%20security%20facelets%20tag%20library) yields among others [this link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch13s11.html) which describes how to manually declare Facelets tag libraries and EL functions. There does thus not seem to be a full integration (i.e. just dropping JAR in webapp without the need to manually create `.taglib.xml` files), they seem to be working on that for future releases.

Comment: Many thanks for your inputs.I have used acegi security `acegi-security` `1.0.6` with JSF 2.0. acegi tag library is working for me.Can you elaborate `Acegi tag library is likely JSP targeted and not Facelets targeted ` what does this mean.